# How to get Facebook access token in App Engine Authenticator

Tags: java, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

In Google App Engine custom `Authenticator`, google access token is received as

```
  String accessToken = req.getHeader("Authorization")
```

Whereas to retrieve facebook access token, I have tried few options but nothing worked out.

```
  String code = req.getParameter("code");
  String code = req.getParameter("access_token");
```

Please advice me on how to retrieve Facebook access token.

Answer (score 0):

Android

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
}
```

iOS

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSString *accessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
}
```

JavaScript (Web)

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } 
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I could get access token in `JavaScript` as mentioned. I want to retrieve FB data in server side `Java` code.